# kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: Failed to change the log file suffix from to .deleted for log segment 0

Tags: apache-kafka

Does anybody know what this error means ?

```
kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: Failed to change the log file suffix from  to .deleted for log segment 0
at kafka.log.LogSegment.changeFileSuffixes(LogSegment.scala:259)
at kafka.log.Log.kafka$log$Log$$asyncDeleteSegment(Log.scala:729)
at kafka.log.Log.kafka$log$Log$$deleteSegment(Log.scala:720)
at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$deleteOldSegments$1.apply(Log.scala:488)
at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$deleteOldSegments$1.apply(Log.scala:488)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at kafka.log.Log.deleteOldSegments(Log.scala:488)
at kafka.log.LogManager.kafka$log$LogManager$$cleanupExpiredSegments(LogManager.scala:411)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$cleanupLogs$3.apply(LogManager.scala:442)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$cleanupLogs$3.apply(LogManager.scala:440)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
at kafka.log.LogManager.cleanupLogs(LogManager.scala:440)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:182)
at kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaScheduler.scala:99)
at kafka.utils.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Kafka seems to work but I'd like to understand what's the message about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this happens when kafka tries to rename the file when its still open. This is the report of the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194).

Comment: Thanks man! Do you know if the issue has been fixed ? It looks still pending.. But the jira refers to 0.8.1 while I have the same issue with 0.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to delete your kafka logs:
C:\tmp\kafka-logs
C:\tmp\zookeeper

At the time of writing this answer the [existing bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194) is still outstanding.